# Azure DevOps- Postman Installation

Tags: postman, azure-devops

I'm trying to install Postman.exe file using DevOps pipeline using below command, when I create a release it is getting succesfully but the app is not getting installed on the server

Can someone please advise me on this?

Appreciate your help!

Code used is below

$installerPath = "D:\ins\Postman.exe"

Start-Process -FilePath $installerPath -ArgumentList '/S'

I have tried to set variable to "Process.clean= false." still no luck